# Is there a way to separately view edits made to own posts and edits made to others' posts?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list

Currently, in the [All Actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) tab in the Activity page, you can see *all* the edits you have made so far under the Revisions tab:

[image]

Sometimes, at least for me, it gets a bit difficult to find edits made to other people's posts amongst a lot of revisions made to my *own* posts.

So I would like to *only* view edits made to own / others' posts (i.e., a separate page to view edits made to *own* posts, and a separate page to view edits made to *others'* posts).

Is there a way to view revisions in this manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't care about the results being up to one week old, you can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Here are two queries, [one for others' posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1603142/edits-to-others-posts) and [one for your own posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1603143/edits-to-own-posts). If you ever get tired of typing your own user ID, I [happen to have a userscript for that](https://stackapps.com/q/8136/34061).

[image]